# how to call another page (class) if user pressed the button? (flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

What to put inside `onPressed` to call another page, for example I want to call `class_one()` after I press the button, what is the solution for it?

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
  // Respond to button press
  },
  child: Text('Kehadiran Anggota'),
)),
```

Comment: kindly add more details about your issue its seems unclear to me

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pushNamed function like this:
`Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/yourScreen');`

 In order for it to work you need to register the route inside MaterialApp like this:

```
MaterialApp(routes: {
  '/': (context) => TelaSplashScreen(),
},)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below to navigate between pages, with `Navigator.push()` you will be able to go next page and back and with `Navigator.pushReplacement()` it will proceed to next page but loses its capability to go back to previous page.

```
Navigator.push(
   context,
   MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => const MemberAttendancePage(),
   ),
);
```